# Javascript RegExp - how to match X only when A is before X and B is after X

Tags: javascript, regex

Given string "AXB", 
I would like to match X only when A is before X and B is after X. However I don't want A or B in my returned match.

I understand that for B it can be done this way: /X(?=B)/ but I am not sure if there is similar way to do so for A (before the match)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a capturing group to capture the value and then refer to group `#1`  to access your match.

```
/A(X)B/
```

Example:

```
console.log('AXB'.match(/A(X)B/)[1]); //=> 'X'
```

Comment: this will return both "AXB" and "X" as match

Comment: Charles, the parentheses capture the `X` to Group 1.  You inspect Group 1, and if it isn't set, there is no match. See sample code inmy answer, which uses the same regex.

Comment: @hwnd thanks hwnd. Though not a default built-in but the simplest work around.

Comment: Charles, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
var the_captures = []; 
var yourString = 'your_test_string'
var myregex = /A(X)B/g;
var thematch = myregex.exec(yourString);
while (thematch != null) {
    // add it to array of captures
    the_captures.push(thematch[1]);
    document.write(thematch[1],"<br />");    
    // match the next one
    thematch = myregex.exec(yourString);
}
```

**Explanation**

- `A` matches the literal `A`
- `(X)` matches `X` and captures it to Group 1
- `B` matches `B`
- The script returns Group 1: `thematch[1]`

**In Other Languages**

JavaScript doesn't have lookarounds or `\K`. In languages that support these, you can directly match `X` without capture groups:

- `A\KX(?=B)` (using lokahead and `\K`, which tells the engine to drop what was matched so far from the final match it returns)
- `(?<=A)X(?=B)` (using lookbehind and lookahead assertions)

Comment: I see what's happening now - Js requires implementation for lookahead.